# Accessing a java HashMap from JSP page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring

I have a controller class in Spring MVC, where i am returning a HaspMap as Model attribute -

```
@ModelAttribute("regPrefix")
public Map<String, String> getRegPrefixesOfDepartmentforGroup(final Model model, final HttpServletRequest request) {
    final Map<String, String> regPrefixOfDept = new HashMap<String, String>();
    regPrefixOfDept.put(regKey, regPrefix);
    return regPrefixOfDept;
}
```

Now in the corresponding JSP page, i am trying to access the Hashmap and store the key/value pairs of the Hasmap in a variable using JavaScript. I am trying like below but its not right. Can anyone suggest how to do that

```
<script>
        $("#deptIdSelection").change(function()
        {
            var obj = document.getElementById("deptIdSelection");
            var textItem = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
            alert(textItem);
            var mapObj = "${regPrefix}";
            for(var key in mapObj)
                alert(key +" ->"+ mapObj[key]);

         }
        );
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to access map values like this:

```
${regPrefix.key}
```

If you want to iterate through the map keys, it is not so easy: JSTL is executed on the server side and is rendered to a plain text - no JavaScript objects are created. The following line `var mapObj = "${regPrefix}";` will be rendered to a string representation of `HashMap`, not to a JavaScript object.

To convert your map to a JavaScript object I suggest you to use one of the following methods:

1) Convert your map to `JSON` and pass it as a `String`. So when it is rendered to a JavaScript code, it will look like a regular JS object: `var mapObj = {"key": "value", ...};`. You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or any other `JSON` library to achieve this:

```
final Map<String, String> regPrefixOfDept = new HashMap<String, String>();
regPrefixOfDept.put(regKey, new Gson().toJson(regPrefixOfDept));
```

And then `var mapObj = ${regPrefix};` (note that you need no quotes around because you want `mapObj` to be a JS object, not a string)

2) Iterate through your map using `<c:forEach>` to generate a JS object:

```
var mapObj = {
    <c:forEach items="${regPrefix}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
      ${item.key}: '${item.value}' ${not loop.last ? ',' : ''}
    </c:forEach>
};
```

In both cases you should be able to then call

```
for(var key in mapObj)
   alert(key +" ->"+ mapObj[key]);
```